# sorting keys (which are also values) on the basis of values in hashes in perl

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

For example, this is my hash

```
     'Level1_A' => {
                                  'Level2_A' => 1071,
                                  'Level2_B' => 3429,
                                  'Level2_C' => 3297
                    },
      'Level1_B' => {
                                  'Level2_A' => 702,
                                  'Level2_B' => 726
                    },
```

And I want an output which should look like

```
  'Level1_A' => {
                              'Level2_B' => 3429,
                              'Level2_C' => 3297,
                              'Level2_A' => 1071

                },
  'Level1_B' => {
                              'Level2_B' => 726,
                              'Level2_A' => 702
                },
```

Ultimately, I want to the keys corresponding to the highest values.

Level1_A___Level2_B___3429

Level1_B___Level2_A____726

Comment: Please show the code that isn't working for you.

Comment: Your output is from Data::Dumper, which just dumps out a representation of the hash reference. Hashes in Perl are never sorted. You can sort a list of keys, by values if needed, and then print the key and value pairs. But Data::Dumper has nothing to do with that.

Comment: my @sorted_keys = sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} } keys %hash;

Comment: Your code sorts them by value, lowest value first. If you want them the other way around, switch `$a` and `$b` or use `reverse`. But it's not clear what your question is yet. Does your `%hash` contain  `( Level1_a => { Level2_B => 1071, ... }, ... )`? Please [edit] your question, inlcude your code there, and amend the actual data structure.

Comment: @simbabque, Actually I posted the dumper output to show the layers of hash. I want to sort the hash so that I can pick up the keys corresponding to the highest values

Comment: So you want the 2nd level key with the highest value?

Comment: yes you are right @simbabque, I want the second level keys to be sorted by the highest value.
Sorry that I am not able to pose my question correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Hashes are inherently unordered and there is no way to sort them. However, you can find the *maximum* of the values of a hash and it is best to use a module to help

[`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) provides `max_by` and will allow you to find the hash key corresponding to the maximum numeric value

Like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::UtilsBy 'max_by';

my $data = {
    'Level1_A' => {
        'Level2_A' => 1071,
        'Level2_B' => 3429,
        'Level2_C' => 3297,
    },
    'Level1_B' => {
        'Level2_A' => 702,
        'Level2_B' => 726
    },
};

for my $k1 ( sort keys %$data ) {

    my $v1 = $data->{$k1};

    my $k2 = max_by { $v1->{$_} } keys %$v1;

    printf "%s %s %s\n", $k1, $k2, $v1->{$k2};
}
```

#### output

```
Level1_A Level2_B 3429
Level1_B Level2_B 726
```